# How to PROVE that some Oracle Stored Procedure has been called without auditing it?

Tags: oracle, trace, auditing

I need to PROVE that some Stored Procedure has been called.

This is a third-party database, so:

- I can't ask to change SP
- I can't ask to audit anything
- I have no DBA access

**This is what I have:**

```
1) DO SOME THINGS ...
2) START FOO STORED PROCEDURE ...
   2.1) WAIT UTIL FOO COMPLETES ...
3) DO SOME OTHER THINGS ...
```

**This is what I need:**

```
1) DO SOME THINGS ...
2) START FOO STORED PROCEDURE ...
    2.1) RECEIVE A RESPONSE FROM ORACLE: "OK! FOO HAS BEEN STARTED!" ...     
    2.2) WAIT UTIL FOO COMPLETES ...
    2.3) RECEIVE A RESPONSE FROM ORACLE: "OK! FOO HAS BEEN FINISHED!" ...
3) DO SOME OTHER THINGS ...
```

Comment: `RECEIVE A RESPONSE FROM ORACLE: "OK! FOO HAS BEEN STARTED!"` and `I can't ask to change anything` are cancelling each other.

Comment: I guess your only option is to find some effect that the procedure always has (e.g. does it write data to a table, or send output to dbms_output) and check for that effect.